# Importing a CSV file using query for MySQL (specifying columns)

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I was trying to import a CSV file into a table with an auto-incrementing column named "id".
I do not want to insert the id column as it numbers itself, but after many tries I cannot get this to work. Here is the query I tried:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\CaliberMap.csv'
INTO TABLE sefeed_calibermap 
(SiteCaliber,SE1Caliber,SE2Caliber,Other1Caliber,Other2Caliber,Other3Caliber,Other4Caliber)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

When I execute the query, I get the following message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY
>   '"' LINES TERMI' at line 4

I'm stumped! I wrote this query after reading examples from many different places on the Internet, so the syntax looks correct.

I'm running PhpMyAdmin version 5.6.10.

Comment: Do you have an ID column in your CSV file?

Comment: If you give us a couple of sample lines from the CSV file, and perhaps also the MySQL table description, we might be better able to help. As an alternative, try using HeidiSQL instead of PhpMyAdmin: it has a wizard to import CSV files, which can help. (HeidiSQL is a desktop program for managing MySQL databases, and I find it a lot easier to use than PhpMyAdmin.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confused I think by the documentation you have read.  Try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\CaliberMap.csv'
INTO TABLE sefeed_calibermap     
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(SiteCaliber,SE1Caliber,SE2Caliber,Other1Caliber,Other2Caliber,Other3Caliber,Other4Caliber);
```

The table fields should be at the end.

Comment: This is correct per the load-data specs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: thanks folks! I'm new to MySQL (thanks to the new MS pricing MSSQL by the cpu core, sending the price into the stratosphere, I'm forced to move to MySQL)